# Errata for Rosen and Ireland's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory"?

Tags: number-theory

Anyone know of an errata list for Rosen and Ireland's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory"? I checked on Springer's web site, but did not find anything.